# Passar matriz de structs como argumento

Tags: c++

Tendo o struct

```
struct bloco {
    bloco () : real(), marcado('.'){}

    char real;
    char marcado;
};
```

Quando eu tento

```
void tabuleiro (int lado, int mina){
    ...
    bloco tab[lado][lado];

    ...

    for (i=0, j=0; lado>i; i++){
        for (j=0; lado>j; j++){
             tab[i][j].real = '.';
        }
    }

    ...

    jogar(tab[lado][lado]);

    return;
}
```

E na função jogar eu tenho

```
void jogar(bloco tab){
    tab[x][y].marcado = 'M'; 
}
```

Eu recebo a mensagem

> no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'bloco' and 'int')
>      tab[x][y].marcado = 'M';

Até onde entendi, isso quer dizer que eu nao passei "tab" como sendo uma matriz, então eu tentei resolver com:

```
void jogar(int lado, bloco tab[lado][lado]){
    tab[x][y].marcado = 'M'; 
}
```

Que me deu a seguinte mensagem

> error: use of parameter 'lado' outside function body
>    void jogar(int lado, bloco tab[lado][lado]){

Eu só queria passar a matriz de structs criada em uma função pra alterá-la na outra, mas não sei como :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O segundo erro que você recebeu é porque você precisa passar um tamanho constante dentro dos colchetes na declaração do parâmetro. "lado" não serve, pois também é um parâmetro. Mesmo que fosse, lado não é uma constante ou *expressão constante*, então não pode ser usado como dimensão da matriz.

Ou seja, você vai ter que fixar o tamanho da sua matriz e, uma vez fixado, fazer algo assim:

```
void jogar(bloco tab[][ALTURA]) { ... }
```

Aparentemente, isso não se encaixa nos seus requisitos, então você pode usar `std:vector`s, que são de tamanho dinâmico. `std::vector` de `std::vector`, no seu caso.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Eu usei `vector <vector<bloco> > tab(lado, vector<bloco>(lado));` e resolveu meus problemas de compilação. Agora surgiram outros de lógica, mas esses eu posso resolver com um pouco de estudo!